# java is not working in my system path

Tags: windows, 64-bit, java

This is my system path (broken at semicolons for readability)

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
>   C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32;%SYSTEMROOT%;
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WBEM;
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X86;
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X64;
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X86;
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X64;;
>   C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;
>   C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;
>   C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
>   C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT`

Is this right or wrong?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate entries?  If something is not working its likely because of the length of the system path.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run java by simply putting `java` in command line, you have to have java bin directory (like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`) in your PATH variable.

You can do this in 2 ways:

- Edit global PATH (`Win + R` > `Sysdm.cpl` > Advanced > Environment Variables... > System variables > "Path" > Edit...). Note: you have to restart `cmd` window to apply PATH changes.
- Export PATH in local `cmd` window (execute: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`). Note: PATH changes apply for current `cmd` window only.

Comment: Furthermore, once you've edited your PATH Environment Variable as mentioned in the answer, it will take effect only in new command prompt windows. Don't expect it to work in already opened windows.

Comment: Thanks Dhiwakar for giving the comment. Answer was improved.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see Java in your %PATH%, but since it can be very large, or dificult to find you should check if you have java.

To check weather you have Java or not you can execute.

```
java -version
```

in your cmd.exe or powershell. This will print the version of the java tool if it can find it.

> C:\Users\Administrator>java -version java version "1.8.0_40" Java(TM)
> SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
> (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode, sharing)

[Here, on Javas site,](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) you have instruncitons how to set it, for each Windows version.

But you can do it easly, from cmd.exe. Just find in your Windows Explorer, most likely under program files where is your Java instalation folder for example:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin

Copy that location and type in cmd.exe

> set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin";%PATH%

You **must add %PATH%** at the and, to keep your environment path and add Java to it.

Thanks to Dhiwakar Ravikumar, I wasnt aware of this.

*once you've edited your PATH Environment Variable as mentioned in the answer, it will take effect only in new command prompt windows.*